# R delete rows from data table using sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I am wondering if R does not support using sqldf to delete rows from a data table. My data looks like this
[image]

and I am trying to delete from a data table using a delete statement. There is no underlying database just a data.table. But hwen I enter the following sql statement:

```
loans_good <- sqldf("Delete from LoansDT1 where status not in ('Current','Default')")
```

I get the following error message:

```
'SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute() or dbSendStatement() instead of dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery().'
```

Since I get the same message for update I am wondering if it is a limitation.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use `sqldf` here? I think this could be done directly using R's standard subsetting operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a FAQ.  See FAQ 8 on the [sqldf github home page](https://github.com/cran/sqldf#8-why-am-I-having-problems-with-update).

The operation did work. The message is a warning message, not an error message.  The message is misleading and you can ignore it. Note that question did not show the complete message -- the complete message does state that it is a warning message.

The warning message comes from RSQLite, not from sqldf itself.  It is caused by non-backwardly compatible change that was introduced into RSQLite at some point; however, as stated the actual operation works anyways.

Also `delete` and `update` act on tables in the database.  They do not return values so even if they work you won't see any result.  If you want a result you have to use a `select` statement after the `delete` or `update` to retrieve the modified table.

Here is an example using the built-in 6 row BOD data.frame.  It deletes the last row as that row has a Time greater than 5.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf(c("delete from BOD where Time > 5", "select * from BOD"))
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
## 2    2   10.3
## 3    3   19.0
## 4    4   16.0
## 5    5   15.6
## Warning message:
## In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
##   SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute() or dbSendStatement() instead of dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery().
```

Note that this is listed in the sqldf issues where a workaround for the message is provided: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/40

Comment: I don't see how this relates to FAQ 8 on the linked page (or any of the other FAQs, although I scanned through them pretty quickly).

Comment: Search the page for *Why am I having problems with update?* to find FAQ 8.

Comment: The FAQ seems to relate to the secondary portion of your answer, about how to actually see the results of an update or delete.  I thought since you started your answer with a reference to the FAQ, it was supposed to relate to the warning from  RSQLite.

Comment: The key problem is not not seeing the result or the message. The key problem is that the code in the question has no effect at all because nothing is returned in the absence of adding a `select`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dbExecute()` to perform delete, update or insert queries.

```
conn <- dbConnect("Put your connection to your database here")

dbExecute(
  conn,
  "Delete from LoansDT1 where status not in ('Current','Default')"
)

dbReadTable(conn, LoansDT1) # Check
```